# Can't show android device in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: android, debugging, usb, adb, device

I have a Android tablet device that can't be showed by android devices on my laptop(T61), but it worked fine on DELL PC with the same OS: Ubuntu 13.04.

I've update the adb to the latest platform-tools:18.0.1 and

```
export ADB_TRACE=all
```

After :

```
$sudo adb kill-server 
$sudo adb start-server
$ adb devices
```

it shows:

> system/core/adb/adb.c::main():Handling commandline()
>   system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_query():adb_query: host:devices
>   system/core/adb/adb_client.c::_adb_connect():_adb_connect:
>   host:version system/core/adb/transport.c::writex():writex: fd=3 len=4:
>   30303063 000c system/core/adb/transport.c::writex():writex: fd=3
>   len=12: 686f73743a76657273696f6e host:version
>   system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4
>   system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4
>   4f4b4159 OKAY
>   system/core/adb/adb_client.c::_adb_connect():_adb_connect: return fd 3
>   system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_connect():adb_connect: service
>   host:devices system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4
>   system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4
>   30303034 0004 system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3
>   wanted=4 system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4
>   got=4 30303166 001f
>   system/core/adb/adb_client.c::_adb_connect():_adb_connect:
>   host:devices system/core/adb/transport.c::writex():writex: fd=3 len=4:
>   30303063 000c system/core/adb/transport.c::writex():writex: fd=3
>   len=12: 686f73743a64657669636573 host:devices
>   system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4
>   system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4
>   4f4b4159 OKAY
>   system/core/adb/adb_client.c::_adb_connect():_adb_connect: return fd 3
>   system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_connect():adb_connect: return fd 3
>   system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4
>   system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4
>   30303030 0000 system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3
>   wanted=0 system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=0
>   got=0
>   List of devices attached

The **List of devices attached** is NOTHING!

But when I used:

```
$lsusb
```

It shows **Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2207:0010**

And the tablet also shows "**USB debugging connected**", which can also be mounted as 
"**USB mass storage**".

So WHY the **adb devices** shows nothing (only on my laptop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the vender ID to **~/.android/adb_usb.ini** and finally found the device.

Steps:

First: `$lsusb`

example result: Bus 001 Device 025: ID **18d1**:0003 Google Inc.

The 18d1 is the vender ID, add it to **~/.android/adb_usb.ini** by

Second: `echo 0x18d1 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

Third:

```
$sudo adb kill-server 
$sudo adb start-server
$adb devices
```